# Scheme prime number assignment

Tags: scheme

I have this Scheme assignment where I need to display whether the integers in the range of 2-100 are prime or not. I know that Scheme does not allow one to change the value of a variable, but given how I did this I was wondering if this is fixable.

```
(let loop ((i 2))
  (begin (print "")
         (let loop ((j i))
           (begin ()
                  (if (and (= (mod i j) 0) (not (= i j)))
                      (print i " is NOT PRIME"))
                  (if (= j 2)
                      (print i " is PRIME")
                      (loop (- j 1)))))
         (if (= i 100)
             (print "done first")
             (loop (+ i 1)))))
```

Comment: Scheme allows changing a variable with `set!`

Comment: Apart from the strange way you write the code, I fear you won's pass the exam if you keep this algorithm to detect primes.  The most direct way to check a prime up to 100 is to keep a vector and see if the input is in that vector.  There are not many primes up to 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to forget about counting/for loops for the moment, look for recursive patterns and helpful abstractions.

For instance this snippet may be helpfull

```
(define (test n)
 (if (prime? n)
     (begin (display i) (display " is prime.") (newline))
     (begin (display i) (display " is NOT prime.") (newline))))
```

Also `(let loop ((var binding) ...) body)` is not what you think it is. It's not a variation of the C `for i=x...` Loop is just a name here, you could just as easily call it hiccup or roses. The form is used where defining an internal recursive function and calling it with specific expressions would do just as well, but where the sub-function wouldn't benifit from highly descriptive function and free variable names.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.

Comment: the defininiton of `prime?` is up to you to write. And as a hint here, you only need to check divisibility for numbers less than or equal to the square root of n, as integer factors of n will come in pairs, one of which must be less than the square root.